# PowerShell: Triming and adding trailing zeroes

Tags: powershell

I have a string which can be from about 5 characters to any given size. What I would like to do is get the first 10 characters, then add 5 trailing zeroes and save the result at another variable. However I need the end string to have 15 characters. So if there are only 9 characters, there should be 6 trailing zeroes. If there are only 8 characters, then 7 trailing zeroes, etc.

> JOE.BLOGS    -> JOE.BLOGS000000
>
> ANDREW.SMITH -> ANDREW.SMI00000
>
> JIM -> JIM000000000000

I am having a particular hard time since the SubString gives me an error if the string is shorter than what I specify:

```
$shadowSAM = $shadowUPN.substring(0,10) + '00000'
```

Plus I am not sure on how to add the correct number of trailing zeroes depending on how long the string actually is (an if/then/else of switch statement would be a cringe-fest).

Is this possible in PowerShell?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: `$s = 'JOE.BLOGS'; $s.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($s.Length, 10)).PadRight(15, '0')`

Comment: @PetSerAl Your answer worked like a charm. I managed to complete my script. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd love to know why the question has a low rating, though. I think the question is quite clear, and I spent hours researching and trying this myself and getting nowhere. So only then I thought of asking the question.

Comment: I think it's because once again there are frustrated people who click anyway ... I give you an "up";)

Comment: Yes pretty valid from my side too. Up from my side and thats a pretty nice answer too @PetSerAl

Comment: Thanks lads. My account is now limited to ask questions, though. Seems like some people are just too miserable no matter what :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
(($str -split '' | select -first 10)  -join '').PadRight(15, "0")
```

or this

```
($str[0..9] -join '').PadRight(15, "0")
```

or this

```
$str.substring(0, [Math]::Min($str.Length, 10)).PadRight(15, "0")
```

or this

```
($str -replace '(.{10}).+','$1').PadRight(15, "0")
```

Comment: `($str[0..9] -join '').PadRight(15, "0")` that will fail with `Set-StrictMode -Version 3` for strings less then 10 characters.

Answer (score 1):

oter solution with "0"*15 to replace padleft

```
 (($str2 -replace '(.{10}).+','$1') + ("0" * 15)).Substring(0, 15)
```

Comment: This one also works perfectly. If you lads say this is better than using padleft, then I will stick this this one. Thanks again.

Comment: This is not a better way, just another way (less legible I agree)  ;)